# Active Admin config documentation

Tags: activeadmin

Is there anywhere that I can find documentation on Active Admin's config options? I haven't found anything yet (other than the code itself).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing to do is look at the source code template for the initializer. There are a lot of undocumented configurables.

https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/blob/master/lib/generators/active_admin/install/templates/active_admin.rb.erb

Comment: Thanks for posting this. I was looking for a place where all of the config stuff was condensed into one area and this looks like it.

Answer (score -1):

http://activeadmin.info/documentation.html

Comment: That was the first thing I thought of. I'm looking for more of a listing of all the configuration options, not the documentation page.